# JavaScript runs only once after page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This script is triggered only once when the page loads.
The page has loaded, click the link, the data came from.
Click the link again, nothing.
Overload the page, the link works, etc.
What is wrong in the script, why it triggered only once?

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('a').click(function() {
            $.get('ajax', function(data) {
                $('#mydiv').html(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="mydiv">
    <a href="#">Update the div!</a>     
</div>
```

Compared the data in the "mydiv" before and after clicking the link:
*before clicking the link*

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <a href="#">
        Update the div!
    </a>
</div>
```

*after link was cliked*

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <a href="#">
            Update the div!
            <!--Here is the data that came from.-->
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You're replacing the `a` element that you put the click handler on, so the `click` event will never fire again because the array in the javascript is static.

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click','a',function()...`. It's called event delegation and allows you to bind events to elements that do not exist yet.

Comment: @blex, thanks, it's solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're overwriting the `a` tag that you attached the click event to, you'd need to rerun the code that attaches the click event again. Or you could use event delegation like blex suggests:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of dynamically created `a` you should use:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
```